# Can an Abjurer wizard use the ability Projected Ward without summoning the Arcane Ward before?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard

Can an abjurer wizard use the ability Projected Ward without summoning the Arcane Ward before? If yes what would happen to the Arcane Ward after using the Projected Ward ability if it has still some hp?

Comment: It would be helpful if you quoted/cited the text of the abilities you are asking about.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your question. Without summoning the Arcane Ward, it won't have HP. Why you are asking the second question?

Comment: I think he might be asking about a zero HP ward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No

Projected Ward description says

> when a creature that you can see within 30 feet of you takes damage, you can use your reaction **to cause your Arcane Ward** to absorb that damage.

If you have no Arcane Ward, you can't cause *[nothing]* to absorb the damage.

If the Arcane Ward is at 0 HP, you can use Projected Ward, but it is useless because the ward cannot absorb any damage.

Arcane Ward expires on long rest, even if it has some hit points left, so you can't use it without summoning the ward after long rest, thus you cannot use Projected Ward after the ward "unsummoned" after long rest.

Comment: Even the name suggests that you can't... however, naming conventions have left a great deal to be desired in the past.

Answer (score 4):

## No - Projected ward requires Arcane Ward in order to function.

Projected Ward:

> when a creature that you can see within 30 feet of you takes damage, you can use your reaction to cause your Arcane Ward to absorb that damage.

The text very clearly implies the ward has to exist before the creature takes damage. That said, you could project a zero HP hp ward onto a target, but it wouldn't do anything.

If the ward has zero hit points, it cannot absorb any HP damage, and so you use your reaction to place a zero HP ward on a creature, and zero HP is absorbed, the rest of which applies fully to the original target.   Effectively wasting your reaction and preventing zero damage.

[Linkie To Wizards](https://dnd5e.fandom.com/wiki/Wizard)